# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_n \to\mathbb{ Z}_m$ is an homomorphisms.

Tags: group-theory

$r:\mathbb{Z}_n \to \mathbb{Z}_m$ defined by $r([x]) = [x], \ \forall [x] \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ is well-defined and is a
homomorphism? Prove your claim. Find the kernels for those functions.

I didn't know what I had to do to prove this, so I searched and find this (but also I don't know how to prove it):

$$r(a+ b\operatorname{mod} n)=(f(a\operatorname{mod}n)+f(b\operatorname{mod}n))\operatorname{mod} m$$

Is there any other way to well-define this function?

**Edit:** Also $m|n$, otherwise there will be elements in $Z_n$ that add to zero mod $n$ but they do not add to zero mod $m$.

Comment: You're missing a condition: $m$ must be a divisor of $n$. Here's a question to ponder. Do you know why writing the phrase "$r([x])=[x]$ for all $x\in\Bbb Z_n$" does **not** describe a well-defined homomorphism when $m$ is *not* a divisor of $n$? Try a small example, like $n=3$ and $m=5$.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I forgot to put that condition!

Comment: Now that you've remembered that condition, see what progress you can make with that additional hypothesis.

Comment: Remember that "well-defined" means "gives the same result, indifferently to the choice of representative from the equivalence class(es)".  Does $r$ send different representatives to the same image?

Answer (score 1):

Let $r:Z_n \rightarrow Z_m$ such that $r([x]_n)=[x]_m$ and $m|n$

If $[x]_n=[y]_n$ then $$n|x-y \Rightarrow m|x-y$$  because $m|n$

So $[x]_m=[y]_m \Rightarrow r([x]_n)=r([y]_n)$ ,proving that $r$ is well defined.

Now let $[x]_n,[y]_n \in Z_n$

$$r([x+y]_n)=[x+y]_m=[x]_m+[y]_m=r([x]_n)+r([y]_n)$$ proving that $r$ is a homomorphism.

Now let $r([x]_n)=[0]_m$

then we have $[x]_m=[0]_m \Rightarrow m|x \Rightarrow x=km$

Thus $Ker(r)=\{[km]_n|k \in \{1,2...n-1,n\}\}$

Comment: I'm not sure if i found the correct Kernel of $r$ so any correction would be appreciated :)